# Interface between rdesktop and gocr

Tags: ocr

I'm trying to integrate gocr to rdesktop.
To do it, I'm thinking to add code to ui_memblt routine. I have two methods:

a) Copy the screen changes (rects) to a shared memory readed by a "daemon" using gocr. My problem with it, I don't know the format of Pixmap, to copy its bytes to a shared memory area.

b) Using the XShm routines:

```
if(ximage==NULL)
 {               
  ximage=XShmCreateImage(g_display, visual, 1, /* g_depth, */ XYPixmap, NULL, &shminfo, g_width, g_height);
  shminfo.shmid=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,ximage->bytes_per_line*ximage->height, IPC_CREAT|0777);
  shminfo.shmaddr=ximage->data=shmat(shminfo.shmid,0,0);
  shminfo.readOnly=True;
  XShmAttach(g_display,&shminfo);
  printf("MIT-SHM: Shared memory KID=%d, at=%p\n",shminfo.shmid,shminfo.shmaddr);
}               
XShmPutImage(g_display, g_wnd, g_gc, ximage, 0, 0, x, y, cx, cy, False);
```

When I executed this code, I'm receiving:

```
MIT-SHM: Shared memory KID=71827465, at=0xb6c25000
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_ShmPutImage)
Serial number of failed request:  78
Current serial number in output stream:  78
```

Any idea?
I'm trying to do a fast-copy (or sharing) between rdesktop and gocr "daemon".